# Should you omit information in variable names that are already specified by properties of that class?

Tags: java, variables, naming-conventions, readability, consistency

For example when you have the `class Room` in which every room gets (or atleast should get) a different room number, do you ever allow yourself that you name that variables `roomNumber` instead of just `room`? Because you already know it's of the `Room` class, you could omit `room` in `roomNumber`, and just leave it `number`. For consistency sake I want to either include this information already specified by the class or omit it always.

```
Class Room {

    private int roomNumber;

    Room(int roomNumber) {
    this.roomNumber = roomNumber;
    }

}
```

or

```
Class Room {

    private int number;

    Room(int number) {
    this.number = number;
    }

}
```

I am thinking about how it would look if you would room.getRoomNumber() or room.getNumber(); and which would make more sense most of the times.

Comment: Are other types of number possible? For example, number of beds?

Comment: Good point. Yes it would make sense for a room to store the number of beds in them as well.

Comment: One should reduce such redundancies, but your example is well chosen: "room number" is a very known notion, whereas "number" is such a no-name. Using an abbreviation here "no"/"nr" might be more to some people's taste. A String even more clear ("Room 013", "Room 12A").

Comment: How about DoorNumber or something similar that doesn't repeat 'room', but does better explain the purpose.

Comment: The other problem that we should also start questioning some day resides in the 'get' prefix. We can ask a Room for its 'number' or 'door number' (I like this one) but what would be the meaning of asking the Room to **get** its number? The problem is that we are forced to say **get** to distinguish between getter and setter methods. And we are so used to add **get** that we don't see it. Languages that use the Smalltalk syntax do not have this problem as you would say doorNumber for the getter and doorNumber: for the setter (BTW, with no parenthesis)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Welcome to slowy's philosophical programming class)

getNumber() may sound okay. But how does it look, when the room has ten more attributes? How does it look for someone else? What if you would have a Type Employee with an employeeNumber and a Reservation with a reservationNumber? How does the business talk about it? How would the label of a web-gui be named for this property?

Keep in mind:

1) Most of the time, it's better to name methods and variables in a way, so that it's easier to understand. If you name something, try to name it, so you don't have to comment it. If the variable is longer than your 24" wide screen tft, well, something went horribly wrong hehe. In your case, I would have commented, that getNumber() will return the room number, just to make it perfectly clear. Not necessary otherwise.

2) Consistency: If the business is talking about a room number, name it room number. From the member variables, to methods, to table columns. If possible. It makes everything easier. This includes methods like "readRoomByRoomNumber()" instead of "readRoomByNumber()".

3) Naming of variables: Also declare "Room room = new Room()" and not "Room r = new Room()". So in the end: "room.getRoomNumber" is so much easier to read than "r.getNumber()" ;-)

Hope this helps,
regards,
slowy

Answer (score 4):

If the Room has other numeric attributes, then make the variables' names more specific. If the room number is the only numeric attribute I think that `room.getNumber()` is enough.